# ImageView not Updating with new URL after activity is reopened

Tags: java, android, imageview

there are simple activities A and B. Activity A launches Activity B and i can select an image as profile image, which first I will upload it to the server and then show the image via the received url. At first when I switch to activity B everything works fine, if there is an image already downloaded its shown in the imageview or it will be downloded and shown. in this case if I select other images to upload, its working just fine and the imageview will show the new images. when I exit the activity and relaunch it, the previously downloded image is shown (if any exists), but any new image uploaded to server won't be shown not even drawables. the imageview won't update at all until I exit the activity again and relaunch it, which in this case the previous image uploaded will be shown but again no new image is shown. so to sum it, first time everything works fine, but for the next times the image is loaded properly only one time.
I've been using Glide and Frisco and thought the problem is caused by them but then used simple ImageView and simple connection to download bitmap and it was the same. it works only one time.

I've been testing both on Nokia 6.1 plus Android 9 and Nexus 5x Android 8.1 and emulators with Android 8.1 and Android 9. I've also tried the release build and still the same.In addition, I'm using AndroidX and the strategy to download image and load them is the same as my previous projects and I'd never faced this issue before.

tried these below before and after loading image and it's not working.
with Glide and Frisco the cache is also disabled. and The urls are completely random so they wont even have the chance to cache them.
here is a sample download and load, its just temporary.

```
 image.setImageResource(0); 
 image.setImageBitmap(null);                                             
 image.invalidate();



new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Bitmap bmp = null;
                        try {
                            trustEveryone();
                            URL url = new URL(user.image_address);
                            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                            Bitmap finalBmp = bmp;
                            ProfileActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    _profileImage.setImageBitmap(null);
                                    _profileImage.setImageResource(0);
                                    _profileImage.invalidate();
                                             _profileImage.setImageBitmap(finalBmp);
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
```

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: @medyas edited the question, its just simple things I've done that before but the behavior is strange

Comment: can you post you full activities code

Comment: @meydas its simpe create  2 activities one with a button launching the other one , and the other acticity having an imageView , I will post it later but its just nothing complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- before using below method, tested it on my backup project before migrating to androidX and it was the same so the problem was not because of androidX

so here is the solution. the activities order : Main->Profile->Gallery->Crop->Back to Profile
to return the results from Crop to Profile I'm using event bus which has to be run on UI thread, so the Activity used to runOnUI... to post the event was CropActivity which was finished after the event is posted, and although I used ProfileActivity.runOnUI ... to load the image when receiving the event from event bus, the whole code was being run on CropActivity so I used another workaround to send results back to previous activity and that solved the problem without the need for invalidate or setting the image to null.